# How should I modify global variables from within a function?

Tags: python, scope, structure, readability

I've been trying to clean up my code for a neural network evolution simulator I'm working on, because it's grown to over 1000 lines and it's very difficult to read. Part of that process involves moving blocks of code from the main loop into their own functions (event handling, drawing to the screen, etc) or their own modules. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to deal with the global variables.

As an example, I have a variable called "selected" that keeps track of a particular neural network creature selected by the user. I want to change the value of this variable in the event handling function when the user clicks on a new creature; I also want to change its value when the creature dies, which happens in a different block of code in its own function.

I understand that I can use the "global" keyword to do this, but my impression is that it's generally poor practice to do so. I also know that I can store these variables in a separate module and import them, but when I'm dealing with 30+ variables, typing "module_name.variable_name" every time I want to modify them seems unnecessarily tedious. I was also considering storing all of these values in a global dictionary so I can modify them from within functions, but again, typing "dict_name['var_name']" each time seems unnecessary.

So essentially my question is, what would be the best practice in this situation? Is it one of these solutions, or is there a cleaner approach? I'd like to make sure I'm on the right track before I spend hours overhauling my code. Thank you for your help!

Comment: global variables are a bad practice, not the use of the global keyword. If you use global variables, use `global` to modify them from within functions.

Comment: The reasons why global variables are fround upon are hardly relevant for such a small program, don't feel bad about it

Comment: Are all of your globals related to user interaction?

Comment: If your value is truly global (in other word singleton), then feel free to use global. It's slightly harder to debug, but you should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

30 global variables is just a big no-no. At some point you'll forget the `global` statement, and you'll create a local variable and will spend hours to debug your code.

you could build a singleton object instead

instead of:

```
a = 12
b = 33
c = "foo"

def run():
   global a
   if a == 34:
      # do something
      a += 1
```

you could create a big wrapping class with all variables as members:

```
class Program:
   def __init__(self):
     self.a = 12
     self.b = 33
     self.c = "foo"
```

now you can access all your variables with the `self` prefix. It may be tedious but at least it's short, and most good IDEs (pycharm, pyscripter, eclipse) propose completion (much better than a dictionary, where you cannot have completion)

```
# let's say it's the main method
def run(self):
   if self.a == 34:
      # do something
      self.a += 1
```

now:

```
o = Program()
o.run()
print(o.a)  # without __ prefix, your data is visible from the outside
```

So using an object not for inheritance, polymorphism or such, but just to define the "global" context and work inside the instance, with `self.` prefix, and say goodbye to `global` variables.